# I have a problen whith AsyncTask class

Tags: java, android, google-api, google-api-client

I am new to android programing and I have two, one problem in the AsyncTask class named RetrieveTokenTask(), in this class I get a token for access email account on gmail, when I call the AsyncTask class create a infinite loop and the message for approbation is open and closed for the app.

The other problem is when I press the button revoke access for data, when try again login in the app not show the Layout with contains data.

I've done this following some tutorials.

Any help would helpful.

Thanks and sorry for any error in my writing but my english is not good.

This code for mi app is the next:

```
`protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

`
        ...

```
    //Initializing google plus api client
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).addApi(Plus.API)
    .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN).build();

}

protected void onStart(){
    super.onStart();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

protected void onStop(){
    super.onStop();
    if(mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()){
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()){
    case R.id.btn_sign_in:
        signInWithGplus();
        break;
    case R.id.btn_sign_out:
        signOutFromGplus();
        break;
    case R.id.btn_revoke_access:
        revokeGplusAccess();
        break;
    }   
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
    if(!result.hasResolution()){
        GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(result.getErrorCode(), this, 
                0).show();
        return;
    }

    if(!mIntentInProgress){
        //Store the connection for later usage
        mConnectionResult = result;

        if(mSignInClicked){
            // The user has already clicked 'sign-in' so we attempt to
            // resolve all
            // errors until the user is signed in, or they cancel.
            resolveSignInError();
        }
    }

}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {
    mSignInClicked = false;
    Toast.makeText(this, "User is connected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    // Get User's information
    getProfileInformation();

    // Update the UI after sign-in
    updateUI(true);     
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int arg0) {
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    updateUI(false);
}

private void updateUI(boolean isSignedIn){
    if(isSignedIn){
        btnSignIn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        btnSignOut.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        btnRevokeAccess.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        llProfileLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    else {
        btnSignIn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        btnSignOut.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        btnRevokeAccess.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        llProfileLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}

/*
 * Sign-in into google
 */
private void signInWithGplus(){
    if(!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()){
        mSignInClicked = true;
        resolveSignInError();
    }
}

/*
 * Method to resolve any sign-in errors
 */
private void resolveSignInError(){
    if(mConnectionResult.hasResolution()){
        try{
            mIntentInProgress = true;
            mConnectionResult.startResolutionForResult(this, RC_SIGN_IN);
        }
        catch(SendIntentException e){
            mIntentInProgress = false;
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        mIntentInProgress = false;
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // Make sure the app is not already connected or attempting to connect
            if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting() &&
                    !mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
                mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            }
        }
    }
}

/*
 * User's information name, email, profile pic 
 */
private void getProfileInformation(){
    try{
        if(Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient) != null){
            Person currentPerson = Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient);

            String personName = currentPerson.getDisplayName();
            String perosnPhotoUrl = currentPerson.getImage().getUrl();
            String personGooglePlusProfile = currentPerson.getUrl();
            String email = Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mGoogleApiClient);

            Log.e(TAG, "Name: " + personName + ", plusProfile: "
                    + personGooglePlusProfile + ", email: " + email
                    + ", Image: " + perosnPhotoUrl);

            txtName.setText(personName);
            txtEmail.setText(email);
            perosnPhotoUrl = perosnPhotoUrl.substring(0,
                    perosnPhotoUrl.length() - 2)
                    + PROFILE_PIC_SIZE;

            new LoadProfileImage(imgProfilePic).execute(perosnPhotoUrl);

            new RetrieveTokenTask(txtToken).execute(email);
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                    "Person informations is null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/*
 * Background Async task to load user profile picture from url
 */
private class LoadProfileImage extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap>{
    ImageView bmImage;

    public LoadProfileImage(ImageView bmImage){
        this.bmImage = bmImage;
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String urldisplay = urls[0];
        Bitmap mIcon11 = null;

        try{
            InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
            mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return mIcon11;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result){
        bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
    }
}

/*
 * Sign-out from google 
 */
private void signOutFromGplus(){
    if(mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()){
        Plus.AccountApi.clearDefaultAccount(mGoogleApiClient);
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        updateUI(false);
    }
}

/*
 * Revoking access from google 
 */
private void revokeGplusAccess(){
    if(mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()){
        Plus.AccountApi.clearDefaultAccount(mGoogleApiClient);
        Plus.AccountApi.revokeAccessAndDisconnect(mGoogleApiClient)
            .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {

                @Override
                public void onResult(Status arg0) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "User acces revoked!");
                    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
                    updateUI(false);
                }
            });
    }
}

private class RetrieveTokenTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    TextViewTkn Tkn;

    private RetrieveTokenTask(TextView tkn){
        this.Tkn = tkn;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String accountName = params[0];
        String scopes = "oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.compose";
        String token = null;
        try {
            token = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(getApplicationContext(), accountName, scopes);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAGTKN, e.getMessage());
        } catch (UserRecoverableAuthException e) {
            startActivityForResult(e.getIntent(), REQ_SIGN_IN_REQUIRED);
        } catch (GoogleAuthException e) {
            Log.e(TAGTKN, e.getMessage());
        }
        return token;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        txtToken.setText(result);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To your second question, an asynctask does not run more than once. If you are trying to reexecute an instance it will not run. You must create new AsyncTask instance every time you want to execute.

You better set a break point in doBackground method and check it.